# Rerun $scope.something function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I bind a function to $scope how can I rerun it within a watch?

```
if($scope.current){
            $scope.$watch('current.new', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
              // how to rerun formvalidation function here
            });
          }


$scope.formvalidation = function () { //.. }
```

Comment: `scope.formvalidation()`?

Comment: Where you want to return? Do you want to return or call `$scope.formvalidation` ?